# How does the Raid Finder work?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

In patch 3.4, a number of Extreme Primals are being moved from the Duty Finder into the Raid Finder. I do a lot of Thordan/Sephirot Extreme runs via the Duty Finder today but have never used the Raid Finder, and the options look a little confusing for a "just let me fight the boss" queue:

[image]

(Picture taken from the [Patch 3.3 notes.](http://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/topics/detail/197e9c8b2f04efdecffe26bebe43b40551d1e3e8#battle))

I don't care if other people have cleared or not cleared; I just would like the fastest queue possible. What options do I need to set in Raid Finder to get a similar experience to Duty Finder today?

Do I set "Requirements: Duty Incomplete" and "Purpose: Duty Completion"? (~80% of my DF groups have new players, so I assume the incomplete pool is larger.)

Also, does the Raid Finder show which roles you are waiting on? For example, in Duty Finder if I see we're 0/2 2/2 4/4 and I'm queued as a healer, I can swap to tank to speed up our queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so, in order:

Matching Requirements: Duty Complete means people need to have completed the duty before to be matched. Incomplete means anyone can be matched (I believe).

Purpose: Practice is for learning the fight, Duty Completion is for actual attempts to clear it.

I'm not sure which purpose is quicker, but Duty Incomplete definitely is the faster matching requirements - there's a lot more people wanting to learn the fight than there are people who have already completed it.